# Django ORM, Sum column values through query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

I have a table with the following values:

| user | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 2017-07-01 |
| John | 20 | 2019-07-01 |
| John | 30 | 2020-09-01 |
| John | 40 | 2021-11-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Dan | -20 | 2019-02-01 |
| Dan | -30 | 2020-04-01 |
| Dan | -40 | 2021-06-01 |

The input of the function is a range of date, for example, as follows:

```
date_start = '2019-01-01'
date_end = '2021-11-07'
```

**Expected output:**

For all users, for each date in this range of date, I want to return the `sum` of the `amounts`, from the current date to all previous dates like this:

| user | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 30 `(10+20)` | 2019-07-01 |
| John | 60 `(10+20+30)` | 2020-09-01 |
| John | 100 `(10+20+30+40)` | 2021-11-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Dan | -20 | 2019-02-01 |
| Dan | -50 `(-20-30)` | 2020-04-01 |
| Dan | -90 `(-20-30-40)` | 2021-06-01 |

**My efforts**

```
def get_sum_amount(self, date_start=None, date_end=None):
    date_detail = {}
    # Minimum date
    if date_start:
        date_detail['date__gt'] = date_start

    # Maximum date
    if date_end:
        date_detail['date__lt'] = date_end

    detail = Financial.objects.filter(Q(**date_detail)) \
        .values('user') \
        .annotate(sum_amount=Coalesce(Sum(F('amount')), Value(0)))
```

but no result.

### UPDATED

The output of the function for the above example is:

| user | amount |
| --- | --- |
| John | 100 |
| Dan | -90 |

Comment: can you post the output here after print it ??

Comment: detail = Financial.objects.filter(Q(**date_detail)) \
        .values('user') \
        .annotate(sum_amount=Sum('amount')))

Comment: I see the output is correct, am I correct?

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy No, Just like the expected output, it should return, for example for `John`  two other dates with values of 30 and 60.

Comment: in this case, it is better to go to shell and write the expression manually to check the output

Comment: the expression  seem to be correct so you must manually filter explicitly without unpacking (**)

Comment: So you want it cumulative per user per date right?

Comment: @BrianDestura Yes,

Comment: It may need `Subqury` but I could not implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`Window`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions with a partition on`user` to run a cumulative sum per user, ordered by the date:

```
detail = Financial.objects.filter(**date_detail).annotate(
    running_amount=Window(
        expression=Sum('amount'),
        partition_by=[F('user')],
        order_by=F('date').asc(),
    )
)
```